# Flask web app pack by py2exe - ImportError: No module named mock

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, py2exe

I am trying to pack my flask web app using py2exe. My setup.py file is as follows:

```
import sys
from glob import glob 
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe
import os
import numpy # to resolve error: libiomo5md.dll: No such file or directory

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

data_files = []
setup(
    console=['run.py'], 
    options={ 
        'py2exe': {
            'packages':['jinja2'],
            'bundle_files': 1,
            'dll_excludes':['MSVCP90.dll', 'libzmq.pyd'],
            'excludes': ['zmq.libzmq'],
            'dist_dir': 'dist/test', 
            'compressed': True, 
            'includes':['zmq.backend.cython','os', 'logging', 'yaml', 'flask'], 
    }
},

    data_files=data_files # Finally, pass the
```

)

I am not using any unittest in my application and I am able to create my executable, However when I try to start my run.exe file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "views.pyc", line 10, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "forms.pyc", line 13, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "wtforms_components\__init__.pyc", line 3, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "wtforms_components\fields\__init__.pyc", line 24, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "wtforms_components\fields\phone_number.pyc", line 1, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "sqlalchemy_utils\__init__.pyc", line 1, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "sqlalchemy_utils\aggregates.pyc", line 373, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "sqlalchemy_utils\functions\__init__.pyc", line 20, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mock
```

In my library.zip folder, I have sqlalchemy folder and subfolder of testing with mock.pyc code.  Also in my Python27\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\testing folder, I have mock.py and mock.pyc codes.  The content of my mock.py code  is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from ..util import py33

if py33:
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock, call, patch, ANY
else:
    try:
        from mock import MagicMock, Mock, call, patch, ANY
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError(
            "SQLAlchemy's test suite requires the "
            "'mock' library as of 0.8.2.")
```

I appreciate if you could help me to resolve the issue.